# (F#) Find Index of element in 2D Array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, f#

I'm currently having some issues finding the index of a specific element in a 2D array. I know that a standard array can use findIndex as seen below.

```
let wantedElemented = 5
let index = Array.findIndex(fun x -> x = wantedElemented) array
```

My question is, how do you apply this to a 2D array (rectangular). Is there a more efficient way than iterating through the entire array comparing each element?

```
for row in 0 .. max do
        for col in 0 .. max do
            if array.[row,col] = wantedElement then 
            let index = (row,col)
            index
            else (-1,-1)
```

If I do have to iterate through the entire array, how would I handle the else conditional without using option types

Comment: If you want "early stop" semantics, you have to make it recursive.

Comment: How would you do so for a 2D array? As far as I know, arrays do not support pattern matching with head & tail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In response to your comment: yes, arrays cannot be matched with head and tail like lists. But they do have indicies! :-)

A recursive function does not have to recurse over the data structure. The recursing path may be defined by something different. For example: why don't we recurse over the array indicies from zero to max (or back)?

```
let find2D needle (arr: int [,]) = 
    let rec go x y =
          if   y >= arr.GetLength 1 then None
          elif x >= arr.GetLength 0 then go 0 (y+1)
          elif arr.[x,y] = needle   then Some (x,y)
          else go (x+1) y
    go 0 0
```

The above solution will scan the array in rows until it finds the `needle`, at which point it will immediately return.

Alternatively, you can produce yourself a *sequence* of optional indicies, and then use `Seq.tryPick` to pick the first element of that sequence that is not `None`:

```
let find2D needle (arr: int [,]) = Seq.tryPick id <| seq {
    for i in 0..(arr.GetLength 0 - 1) do
        for j in 0..(arr.GetLength 1 - 1) do
            if arr.[i,j] = needle 
                then yield Some (i,j) 
                else yield None
}
```

Because of how sequences work (they're lazy), this will only iterate until the first `Some` is found, and then stop. This is slightly more straightforward (as far as readability goes), but also slightly less performant than the plain recursive solution above, because here we incur the overhead of creating and maintaining the sequence.

Comment: As noted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49890136/136675 if you use the "=" operator on a generic type in a non-inline function then you can have bad performance. It's fine for standard types, and for reference types, but it will box non-standard value types, thus I would recommended implementing the code with a predicate function, as per the previously mentioned link.

Comment: @PaulWestcott This is not what the question was about. I try not to overload my answers with unrelated details when the person asking the question seems like a novice.

Answer (score 2):

Fyodor Soikin was referring to something like...

```
module Array2D =
    let findIndex f (array:'a[,]) =
        let xStart = array.GetLowerBound 0
        let xEnd   = array.GetUpperBound 0
        let yStart = array.GetLowerBound 1
        let yEnd   = array.GetUpperBound 1
        let rec iterate i j =
            if   f array.[i,j] then Some (i, j)
            elif j < yEnd      then iterate i (j+1)
            elif i < xEnd      then iterate (i+1) yStart
                               else None
        iterate xStart yStart

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let testArray = Array2D.init 20 20 (fun _ _ -> 0)
    testArray.[13,12] <- 1

    match testArray |> Array2D.findIndex (fun x -> x = 1) with
    | Some (x,y) -> printfn "found at (%d,%d)" x y
    | None -> printfn "not found"

    0
```

Also, the reason for doing it with a predicate function, rather than looking for the specific value is due to the way that f# does equality checks (otherwise if you were to replace with element comparison then I would recommend that the function be marked "inline")

Answer (score 2):

Another idea is to have a function that lazily enumerates the individual rows of the 2d array and then tries to find the element those rows:

```
let rows arr2D =
    seq {
        for i in Array2D.base1 arr2D .. Array2D.length1 arr2D - 1 -> arr2D.[i, *]
    }

let find2D arr2D elem =
    arr2D
    |> rows 
    |> Seq.mapi (fun i arr ->
        Array.tryFindIndex ((=) elem) arr 
        |> Option.map (fun j -> i, j)) 
    |> Seq.pick id
```

Or if the element can be found at multiple places and you want a list of all of them:

```
let findAll2D arr2D elem =
    arr2D
    |> rows 
    |> Seq.mapi (fun i arr ->
        Array.tryFindIndex ((=) elem) arr 
        |> Option.map (fun j -> i, j)) 
    |> Seq.choose id
```

Comment: Using sequence is a nice idea to achieve laziness, but it doesn't go far enough: you're losing a lot of memory and cycles creating all those intermediate arrays. More elegant would be to create a sequence that iterates over single cells.

Answer (score 0):

Using standard F# libraries you may implement such generic indexes finding function for `Array2D` as below:

```
let findIndexes f (aa: 'a[,]) =
    let mutable found = None
    aa |> Array2D.iteri (fun x y a -> if found.IsNone && (f a) then found <- Some(x,y))
    found
```

and use it as

```
findIndexes ((=)soughtValue) yourArray
```

This implementation apparently scans the whole array with `Array2D.iteri`, but comparison after the first match may be slightly optimized via short circuiting in comparison expression above.

And finally, I'd stick to returning search result via idiomatic `Option<int,int>`  . If for whatever reason you want return the search result without using the option, then an `int*int` tuple will suffice using some "impossible" pair of indexes like (-1,-1) as initial `found` value and indicator of search failure, or throw an exception on search failure like `Array.findIndex` does.

Comment: Any specific reason for downvoting?